# Linux RAID mdadm: what does 'Events' mean?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid1

When I type

mdadm --detail /dev/md0

I get a lots of useful information most of which I understand. However I also get a line that reads:

`Events : 0.710`

Where the number varies.

Naively, I thought an event either happened or it didn't. How can I have only 0.710 of an event? Or if you prefer why is "Events" not an integer value?

EDIT

After seeing user's answer below, I dug into the code a bit and found

`#if  __BYTE_ORDER ==  __BIG_ENDIAN

144         __u32 events_hi;        /*  7 high-order of superblock update count   */

145         __u32 events_lo;        /*  8 low-order of superblock update count    */

...

148 #else

149         __u32 events_lo;        /*  7 low-order of superblock update count    */

150         __u32 events_hi;        /*  8 high-order of superblock update count   */

...

153 #endif`

So "Events" is high-order and low order of "superblock update count" https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Superblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually [1 64-bit integer split in two.](https://github.com/brain0/mdadm/blob/master/super0.c#L301)

```
printf("\n         Events : %d.%d\n\n", sb->events_hi, sb->events_lo);
```

[events_hi and events_lo are two 32-bit halves of one 64-bit number.](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Event) Unless you have more than 2^31 "events," you'll probably only ever see one of those.

As far as what they mean, I'll quote [the wiki page:](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Event)

> An 'event' is one of:
>
> - switch from 'active' to 'clean'
> - switch from 'clean' to '
> - device
> - device is
> - spare replaces a failed device after a rebuild
>
> Notice a normal read/write is not an event.
>
> None of these are meaningful for RAID0, so the 'events' counter on
> RAID0 should be stable.
>
> Unfortunately, the number looks like a decimal but isn't. It is a
> 64bit number. We print out the top 32 bits, a period and then the
> bottom 32 bits. Maybe it'll be 'fixed' someday...

Comment: Ah ha! So the .710 is 710 (presumably) low priority events. Many thanks for digging this out. I wonder if there is a list of "events_lo" type events (and indead events_hi) anywhere.